# Pass multiple values from spring form jsp to spring controller on submit

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I've a table which has multiple columns as in my database table. Few of the columns are editable and the values entered by the user should be updated back in the database on click of submit. For this Ive a foreach loop with value as HashMap of list of bean.
Below is my foreach loop:

```
<c:forEach items="${feeType.value}" var="feeItem" varStatus="feeVar">                    
<td >[b]<form:checkbox disabled="true" class="editable${ifeeCount}" path="includeFeeValue" value="${feeVar.index}"/> [/b]</td>
<td >${feeItem.feetypeId} </td>
<td >${feeItem.feeValue} </td>
<td >[b]<form:input class="editable${ifeeCount}" disabled="true" path="${feeItem.overridenFee}" value="${feeItem.overridenFee}"/>[/b]</td>
    <td><form:errors path="overriddenFee" cssClass="error" /></td>
<td >${feeItem.lastUpdatedBy} </td>
<td >${feeItem.lastUpdatedDate} </td>

<td > ${feeItem.approvedBy}</td>
<td >${feeItem.approvalDate}</td>

<td align="left">[b]<form:input class="editable${ifeeCount}" disabled="true" path="feeComments[${feeVar.index}]"/>[/b]</td>
<td><form:errors path="feeComments" cssClass="error" /></td>
```

I'm iterating through a map called feeApprovalByFundId which is Map>. How do I get the updated values of the columns like checkbox, input box? I'm able to get in a String or String array but I won't know to which key was that mapped to. (Eg. Fund1 will have 10 fees - I will have under one hashmap key).
I tried iterating like this :

```
Collection<List<MyBaseBean>> newList = paswFeeMaintForm.getFeeApprovalByFundId().values();
for(List<MyBaseBean> myList: newList){
for(MyBaseBean myBean : myList){
    System.out.println("Overriden fee : "+myBean.getOverridenFee());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `path` in the form control binding is a string that represents a property binding expression. When the form is rendered, Spring knows what `feeItem` is due to the JSTL context in which the form control is being rendered. But on POST, that context is lost, so `feeItem` doesn't make sense.

Instead, given a form bean like this:

```
public class FormBean {
    private Map<Integer, ChildBean> children = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Integer, ChildBean> getChildren() { return children; }   
}

public class ChildBean {
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

And a controller like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("formBean")
public FormBean createFormBean() {
    FormBean bean = new FormBean();
    bean.add(new ChildBean("Joe", 5));
    bean.add(new Childbean("Sam", 10));
}

@RequestMapping(...)
public String post(@ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean formBean) { ... }

@RequestMapping(...)
public String get(@ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean formBean) { ... }
```

In the view you would do this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="formBean">
    <c:forEach items="${formBean.children}" varStatus="s">
        <form:input path="children[${s.index}].name" />
        <form:input path="children[${s.index}].age" />
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

The rendered form elements would look something like:

```
<input type="text" name="children[0].name" />
<input type="text" name="children[0].age" />
<input type="text" name="children[1].name" />
<input type="text" name="children[1].age" />
```

Note that this is the standard [indexed property](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html) syntax. Now, on the server side, there is enough context to determine which item in the collection should be modified.

For a map, the following no longer applies:

Also note that you don't have to return a list, but can specify the bean method to take an index and a single item, allowing you to define sparse collections (if you haven't constructed the collection ahead of time).

Comment: Based on each of the fund code I should display it's coresponding fee types

Comment: your answer is for the List<Bean> but I've a Map<String,List<Bean>> which is a little more complicated.

Comment: Then make the property type `Map<String, List<Bean>>`.

Comment: Can you please alter your answer for the same?

Comment: I edited the answer - all I did was literally change the text `List<ChildBean>` to `Map<Integer, ChildBean>`.

Comment: All that is working fine for me. How do I pass the input text value is my question : <form:input path="children[${s.index}].name" /> How can I add the parameter here. Since the List<Bean> is the value of the Map. How will my input tag recognize it?

Comment: What is the value of the map key? The expression in `${...}` should specify that value. The map key value should be passed to the server in the POST. I calculated from `s.index`, but you might calculate from the `var` attribute of `c:forEach`.

Comment: ${feeType.value.overridenFee} doesn't work right? I should set overridenFee of the Bean present in the list of the Map - Map<String,List<Bean>>

Comment: Then you need a `${...}` value for the map key and `${...}` value for the list. I have no idea what the structure of any of these are, so I can't tell you what those values would be. Are you understanding how a property expression is mapped to the form bean?

Comment: Yes I'm able to figure that out. But since I've a List within a Map, I'm finding it tough to retrieve in my controller. I can get them as an array but I won't be able to separate them based on the key.

Comment: By converting to an array, you are destroying structure and thus you will not be able to map by key, unless you have some way to recreate structure. Instead of converting to an array, you can preserve the original structure using nested `c:forEach`, one for each level of the structure. Thus, with structure preserved, it is straightforward to construct the correct property expression.

Comment: yeah that's correct. That's the one I'm unable to figure out and need help on.

Comment: I have provided two ways to do it.